# how do you naviagte around a database in a windows form app c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple c# application which display data from a access database

```
    private void DisplayRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        // Check that we can retrieve the given row
        if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
            return; // nothing to display
        if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
            return; // the index is out of range

        // If we get this far then we can retrieve the data
        try
        {
            DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
            SurnametextBox.Text = row["Surname"].ToString();
            FirstNametextBox.Text = row["Firstname"].ToString();
            PhonetextBox.Text = row["Phone"].ToString();
            ContactTypetextBox.Text = row["ContactType"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Now it shows the first record in the database and that is it, i have next and back buttons in place in order to click through the data but what code is needed to display the next record?

Comment: with a name like that please tell me this a database about trains :D
On topic, this is an exact duplicate of your question from like 10 mins ago.... have you tried anything? whats the error? have you tried debugging?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? You posted what's working, but you didn't show us where you're having trouble.

Comment: Yes it is homeowrk, I dont know where to begin thats why im asking. all I need to some direction into how to code a button which will help me go from one record to the next

Answer (score 1):

Create a class variable, so you can remember which row index you are having currentlly. So when you click NEXT, add +1 to this variable, and when pressing PREVIOUS subtract from it (-1).
And use the variable afterwards.

```
class Form1
{
    int counter;
    void ButtonForth_Click()
    {
       counter++;
       YourMethod();
    }

    void ButtonBack_Click()
    {
       counter--;
       YourMethod();
    }

    void YourMethod()
    {
        DataRow row = table.Rows[counter];
        // more code...
    }
}
```

Comment: with the added function of if it reaches 0 and you try to go back one it would wrap around and set it at the highest number, or if you reach the highest number it wraps around to the lowest number, nice functionality for fluidity :D which i think is nicer than checking if its negative and disabling the button if it would go into negatives or beyond the range

Comment: Brillaint, sorry to have to ask but what else is needed, i am a designer not a coder but uni work is forcing me down this route against my will! can someone explain the last line of code and what comes next? thank you.

Comment: It comes the same as you did in your example (bellow that line).

Answer (score 1):

RhysW: thx for pointing that out. I was just simply showing the basics of the pattern code. Sure there is plenty to do to make it work smoothly.

This is how it can be done approx:

```
class Form1
{
    int counter;
    DataTable table; //class variable so we can access to the reference from all over the class

    void ButtonForth_Click()
    {
       if(counter < table.Rows.Count)
          counter++;
       YourMethod();
    }

    void ButtonBack_Click()
    {
       if(counter > 0)
          counter--;
       YourMethod();
    }

    void YourMethod()
    {
        DataRow row = table.Rows[counter];
        if(row.Count > 0 )
        {
           SurnametextBox.Text = row["Surname"].ToString();
           FirstNametextBox.Text = row["Firstname"].ToString();
           PhonetextBox.Text = row["Phone"].ToString();
           ContactTypetextBox.Text = row["ContactType"].ToString();
        }
        //no need of try, catch block, is there are all the names correct (textobxes, and columns of datatable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but I am still having no luck, I have enter the code as above and the buttons still won't cycle through the data :/ The error is 'Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure rowIndex is getting incremented before this function is called. Otherwise the code looks good.